# sum of square roots

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory

I was wondering what the estimate for the value
$$
S= \sum_{j=1}^N \sqrt{j}
$$
is? Is there a way (or a formula) to estimate it well?
I am sure it is close to $\int_1^N \sqrt{t} dt$, but I guess I 
was interested in estimating it better. 
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! I believe that your approximation is in fact, decent. If you want to be more precise, I'd build on the fact that $S$ can be rewritten as a generalized harmonic number, which is related to Riemann and Hurwitz zeta functions. These 2 functions are widely studied and many numerical/functional approximations exist.

Comment: $S_N=-\zeta\left(-\frac{1}{2},N+1\right)-\frac{1}{4\pi}\zeta(3/2)$

Comment: Your approximation vs. the actual thing: http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427erldcv6sefu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Euler-Maclaurin series.
According to Maple, as $N \to \infty$
$$S = \frac{2}{3}\,{N}^{3/2}+\frac{1}{2}\,{N}^{1/2}+\zeta  \left( -1/2 \right) +\frac{1}{24}\,N^{-1/2}-{\frac {1}{1920}}\,{N}^{-5/2}+{\frac {1}{9216}}
\,{N}^{-9/2}+O \left( {N}^{-13/2} \right) 
$$